# A question from inverse trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

> If $(\cot^{-1} x)^2 -7(\cot^{-1}x)+10>0$ then $x$ lies in the interval?(One or more than one correct)
>
> A)$(\cot 5, \cot 2)$
>
> B)$(-\infty,\cot 5)\cup (\cot2,\infty)$
>
> C)$(-\infty,\cot 5)$
>
> D)$(\cot2,\infty)$

My attempt-

I reached upto this point-
$(t-5)(t-2)$ where $t=\cot^{-1}x$.

I dont know what to do after that since $\cot^{-1}$ is a decresing function will it have any impact ?

Comment: What is the range of your $\cot^{-1}(x)$ ?

Comment: nothing specific, $R-(-1,1)$

Comment: Generally it is taken to be $(0, \pi)$

Comment: oh im so sorry i mistook for domain. my bad

Comment: Please consider rereading the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). You should find commands such as `\cot` $\cot$ and `\cup` $\cup$ helpful.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your analysis, you should see that $\cot^{-1}(x) \in R \setminus [2,5]$. But taking range of $\cot^{-1}(x)$ to be $(0, \pi)$, we can only have $(0,2)$ as solution

$$\cot^{-1}(x) \in (0,2) \\ 
\implies x \in (\cot(2),\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \cot (x))$$

Or equivalently $x \in (\cot(2), \infty)$

Comment: what if the range exceeds 5?

Comment: @Lokesh It depends on Range you are working with. You haven't clarified that.

Comment: ok wait ill clarify it and edit the question.

Comment: @Lokesh Look, the function can only give values in its range. $\cot^{-1}(x)$ can only give values in its range, that is $(0,\pi)$. $\cot^{-1}(5)$ is not well defined for this function.

Comment: Oops my answer is incorrect. I have solved $< 0$ whereas the question is $>0$.

Comment: please correct it fast then. Thank you.

Comment: @Lokesh Done...